# Installing Teamcity build agent as a user: failed to install the service. selected account does not have enough rights

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, teamcity

I want to install a TeamCity Build Agent as a user. When entering my user credentials here:

[image]

I always get this error:

[image]

**NOTE: My account (user) is an administrator with full permission!**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The error message says it does not have *"enough rights to run as a service"*,
this is slightly different from just being an administrator.

1. Go to **Control Panel> Administrative Tools> Local Security Policy**.
2. Select **Local Policies> User Rights Assignment**.
3. Scroll down through the list of policies and look for **Log on as a service**.
4. Add the account you're using to the list of accounts with this right.

That should in theory be all you need to allow the service to run under that user.

Comment: @Kamrad not a clue I'm afraid. Maybe have a look for something called secedit? I think it might be the command line equivalent executable but I don't know what versions of Windows it's available on or how to use it.

Comment: Actually I found solution already,
You should download NTRights.exe 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657
and then go to directory where it was installed and run next command
ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight -u userName -m \\COMPUTERNAME

Comment: After setting this I just re-ran the installer and this time it worked fine.

Comment: This link may be helpful for those trying to do this on Windows 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-rights-assignment

Comment: This worked for the error, but now my agents are in a disconnected state. I've even restarted the server for good measure. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JPDamstra, there's usually something in the agent logs to indicate why they won't start. Occasionally I find they take forever to upgrade, or get stuck in a loop of restarting.

Answer (score 2):

The best powershell command that I have found for this is:

```
Grant-Privilege -Identity $SERVICE_USERNAME -Privilege SeServiceLogonRight
```

Requires use of the [Carbon framework](http://get-carbon.org/Grant-Privilege.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Windows 10 Home user and the steps above did not work for me, but the following did:

1. Enable gpedit.msc by running the batch file as explained here under **Method 1**: https://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/
2. Run gpedit.msc [image]
3. Go to **Local Computer Policy** / **Computer Configuration** / **Windows Settings** / **Security Settings** / **Local Policies** / **User Rights Assignment** [image]
4. Double-click **Log on as a service**
5. On the window that appears, click **Add User or Group...** [image]
6. Enter your username and click the **Check Names** button [image]
7. Your name will be modified, adding the machine name as the prefix. Click **OK** [image]
8. Click **OK** on the **Log on as a service Properties** window to apply the change. [image]

It is a little bit of a pain, but after doing that, I was able to continue installing TeamCity